# Как вывести float в целом виде без экспоненты?

Tags: c#, float

[image]
Как можно записать это в виде обычной записи(т.е. 123...) а не с E+19? Мой фрагмент кода, вводимое число записывается в переменную в этом странном виде, как на картинке

```cs
Console.WriteLine("enter full number");
float full = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: [Типы форматирования в .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types)

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("##################################.#####################################"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно так

```
var full = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine));
var dec  = full.ToString("F0");
```

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Не работает!  Жалуется на var dec = full.ToString("D"); (System.FormatException: "Недопустимый описатель формата.")

Comment: "D" работает только с целыми числами, правильно будет "F0", при условии что нет дробной части

Comment: не помогло, в переменной dec записывается 7 чисел, а дальше идут 0(всего цифр 11, как и во вводе!)

Comment: можно ли как-то заставить float записывать так, как мне нужно? (проблема не во вводе)

Comment: @Jrol123, вы понимаете, что в 4 байта невозможно уместить число любой произвольной длины без потери точности?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а точно, спасибо что поправили)

Comment: @Jrol123, возьмите тип Double, и все будет норм)